# How to add subview to a webview so that the subview would scroll along with webview?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, addition, subview

I have webview.

Now I want to add a subview to it. I added it using addsubview method.

The view got added, but did not scrolled with webview.

I want my subview to be scrolled with the webview.

How can I do that?

Regards,
Akshay.

Comment: That's strange to add a subview to an webview. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: Here is the solution http://stackoverflow.com/q/43533068/6521116

Answer (score 17):

You simply need to add your subview to the `UIScrollView` of the `UIWebView` like this to have your subview scroll with the webview content:

```
[webView.scrollView addSubview:youSubView];
```

Comment: For the record, the `scrollView` property was added in iOS 5.0.

Comment: indeed only available post-iOS 5.0, but this is a fabulous trick; i just used it to allow my spinner for loading into a webView to be housed withing the confines of the UIWebView.  perfect!

Comment: it can only help me to add upto 126 subview's

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that, you would need to tinker with the internals of `UIWebView` and find out it's view hierarchy, so you can add the subview inside the scoller.

It's probably easier to tweak your HTML *inside* the view, so you can include something similar to your custom view (text or an image) in it.

You can later interact with your "fake view" via Javascript.

Comment: Is it possible if I have a UIWebView object? 
I have to work with existing webView object and cannot create new one by subclassing..

Answer (score 0):

Try this,  it will work

[[[yourwebview subviews] objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:yoursubview];

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want your uiview on a region with movie id in the html.  Check my **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43533068/6521116)** here.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    self.wk.evaluateJavaScript("var rect = document.getElementById('movie').getBoundingClientRect();[rect.left, rect.top];") {
        (result, error) -> Void in
        print(result)
        self.player.view.frame.origin.x = (result as! Array)[0]
        self.player.view.frame.origin.y = (result as! Array)[1]
    }
}
```